# Limit parallel execution of command in CMake

Tags: cmake

I want a certain command in a CMake rule to be executed in series rather than in parallel. That is because the invoked executable has side-effects. The command is multiplied by a foreach loop with slightly different options. All other commands should be executed in parallel.

Is that easily possible in CMake? Other build systems like Qbs have named job pools for that purpose.

I don't want to set CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL because that would serialize all rules.

Comment: `That is because the invoked executable has side-effects` What side effects? Are  you sure then you can't run it in parallel anyway?

Comment: I assume this is for a custom command. If you are only using Ninja try JOB_POOLS: "Specify a pool for the Ninja generator. Incompatible with USES_TERMINAL, which implies the console pool. Using a pool that is not defined by JOB_POOLS causes an error by ninja at build time."

Comment: > What side effects? Are you sure then you can't run it in parallel anyway?

@KamilCuk, Yes, I have to call a proprietary tool that creates temporary files at a fixed location and which must not run in parallel.

Comment: `at a fixed location` How fixed? :) In an absolute path?

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes it is a fixed absolute location. This tool is very poorly engineered and there is nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @jpr33 thank you. Job pools was exactly what I was looking for. You may turn your comment into an answe.

Comment: If you are on linux, you may want to research per process private file system mount points ie. `unshare` (see `bubblewrap`). You can redirect that fixed location to a custom location and parallelize the work anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks, but unfortunately I have to work on Windows. I do it for the money only. Job pools fulfill my needs. I don't have time to force this proprietary crap application to behave nicely and allow parallel builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for a custom command.

If you are only using Ninja try JOB_POOLS:

"Specify a pool for the Ninja generator. Incompatible with USES_TERMINAL, which implies the console pool. Using a pool that is not defined by JOB_POOLS causes an error by ninja at build time."